# how to perform count using nested select in a select statement

Tags: mysql, count, nested-loops

So here is the issue. I'm trying to write a new fillrate report because the one built in is not good enough...  I'm trying to run a single select statement to return both, a count of how many times an item was ordered for a specific month, and then also a count of how many times it was invoiced/shipped in full.

This code is obviously wrong, I also currently have it restricted to only look at AUG of 2015, but that is just to simplify results during testing.

I can't figure out how to do the 2nd count... This is what I was trying (brain stuck on old for each loop logic):

```
select inv_mast.item_id, 
       inv_mast.item_desc,
       "YEAR" = year(oe_line.required_date), 
       "MONTH" = month(oe_line.required_date),
       "ORDERS" = count(1),
       "HITS" = (
                  select count(1)
                  from invoice_line
                where invoice_line.order_no = oe_line.order_no 
                  and invoice_line.oe_line_number = oe_line.line_no
                  and invoice_line.qty_shipped = oe_line.qty_ordered
               )            


from oe_line, 
     inv_mast,
     inv_loc

where inv_mast.inv_mast_uid = oe_line.inv_mast_uid 
  and inv_mast.delete_flag = 'N'
  and inv_mast.inv_mast_uid = inv_loc.inv_mast_uid
  and inv_loc.location_id = '101'

  and year(oe_line.required_date) = '2015' 
  and month(oe_line.required_date) = '8'


group by inv_mast.item_id, 
         inv_mast.item_desc,
         year(oe_line.required_date), 
         month(oe_line.required_date)

order by inv_mast.item_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it would seem like you could rewrite the query to use a left join on the invoice_line table instead. Without any proper test data I can't guarantee it is correct, but I think it should be.

Besides the left join I also changed to explicit joins and moved the aliases as I don't think MySQL supports the `alias = column` syntax.

```
select inv_mast.item_id, 
       inv_mast.item_desc,
       year(o.required_date) as "YEAR", 
       month(o.required_date) as "MONTH",
       count(1) as "ORDERS",
       count(invoice_line.order_no) as "HITS"
from oe_line o
join inv_mast on inv_mast.inv_mast_uid = o.inv_mast_uid 
join inv_loc  on inv_mast.inv_mast_uid = inv_loc.inv_mast_uid
left join invoice_line on invoice_line.order_no = o.order_no 
                      and invoice_line.oe_line_number = o.line_no
                      and invoice_line.qty_shipped = o.qty_ordered
where inv_mast.delete_flag = 'N'
  and inv_loc.location_id = '101'
  and year(o.required_date) = '2015' 
  and month(o.required_date) = '8'

group by inv_mast.item_id, 
         inv_mast.item_desc,
         year(o.required_date), 
         month(o.required_date)

order by inv_mast.item_id;
```

Comment: Once I eliminated the 'o' abbreviations, this was perfect.